# there is trace/breakpoint trap when using pointer in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
//#include "ans.c"

int *decompressRLElist(int *nums, int numsSize, int *returnSize);

int main()
{
    int nums[] = {39, 1};
    int length = 2;
    int returnlength;
    int *p = decompressRLElist(nums, length, &returnlength);
    int *pp = p;
    while (returnlength-- != 0)
    {
        putchar(*(p++)+'0');
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int *decompressRLElist(int *nums, int numsSize, int *returnSize)
{
    int *ans = (int *)malloc(100);
    int *p = ans;
    *returnSize = 0;
    numsSize /= 2;
    while (numsSize-- != 0)
    {
        while ((*nums)-- != 0)
        {
            *(p++) = *(nums + 1);
            (*returnSize)++;
        }
        nums += 2;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

I am working on a leetcode problem, after running the debugger there is an exception named trace/breakpoint trap occurred. It is confusing that when the length of array is shorter than 39, the error does not occur, but when equal or longer than 39, the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One integer is usually 4 bytes, though it can be different deppending on your system, so when you allocate 100 bytes it's only good for 25 integers, you should use:

```
int *ans = malloc(100 * sizeof(*ans));
```

The `malloc` cast is also unnecessary.

The fact that the error only starts at array size of 39 can only be attributed to undefined behaviour.